# I get all the projects while I only want the projects related to that client

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, laravel-9

I have two tables, one named **Clients** and the other named **Projects** linked together *via a foreign key* (this is client_id, present in Projects).

In the view related to the list of all clients, I have an additional field that shows me the number of active projects for each client.

So far everything ok! When I click on the number of active projects, I am shown all the projects while I only want those related to that client. So I believe the error is in the condition.
(the withCount below is used to provide me with the number of tasks present in each project)

```js
public function index($id)
    {
         $projects = Project::withCount(['tasks'=> function (Builder $query) use ($id){
        $query->where('client_id', $id);
    }])->get();
        return view('project.index', compact('projects'));
    }
```

There is certainly an error in the condition written above.

Can anyone kindly help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Project::where('client_id', $id)->withCount('tasks')->get();
```

You were trying to find the client_id inside the tasks

Comment: Perfect, I thank you infinitely

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have some kind of route that is `/client/{client}/projects`

You can pass the client into the controller using Route Model binding, and call the projects relationship directly:

```
public function index(Client $client) {
  $client->projects()->get();
}
```